# Gridster inside another div constrained by height

Tags: gridster

If gridster is placed inside another div with a constrained height and width - you cannot move/resize a widget outside that constrained height/width.

```
<div id="header" style="height:50px;">Hello World!</div>
    <div id="g-parent" style="position:relative;height:300px;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="g" class="gridster">
        <ul>
            <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">0</li>
            <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">1</li>
            <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">2</li>
            <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">3</li>
            <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">4</li>
            <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">5</li>
            <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">6</li>
            <li data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">7</li>
            <li data-row="4" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">8</li>
            <li data-row="5" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Gridster](http://gridster.net) scrolls only if Gridster width/height equals to page/window.
If gridster part has it's own scroll it doesn't scroll while your are dragging or resizing it stops at the boundries of it restricted height.

Take a look at the simple example http://jsfiddle.net/bgandham/0ky0u01h/. I want to move something below the visible area and I can't move it - same with the resizing.

Any ideas?